# How do enable your recipe schema for Google Assistant to share to Google Home Hub

Tags: actions-on-google, jsonschema

I have seen the ability to enable the search results from Google for recipes and how-tos using schema to be shared to the Google Home Hub. I believe it was in the Google Actions documentation but I didn't bookmark it and of course, now I can't find the documentation. Anybody know where I can find that, please.

I've searched everywhere in the documentation for Google Assitant.

Answer (score 0):

[Recipes](https://developers.google.com/actions/content-actions/recipes) are one type of web-based content Actions. Once you set up the schema, then Google search and Assistant will be able to query and process your schema. It's one type of [structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data).

Comment: That I understand but I thought there was a way to allow the recipe to be able to push to the Google Home Hub recipe for the user to access from home.

Comment: That's part of the search results. It's not something that you, as a developer or content owner, would build yourself.